# OnTriggerStay detecting collision with itself

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to detect collision between the player and the objective. In order to that I've set the IS TRIGGER in both of them and wrote this script:

[image]

Attached it to the Objective game object.

When I run the game, my console shows the Objective Tag and doesn't show the player tag. That is what I want to do. Does anybody know what its doing?

Comment: Please post your code not a screenshot of it. What do you mean  by *"my console shows the Objective Tag, and doesn't show the player tag"*?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your player is tagged as "Player" 
Check col.gameobject.CompareTag("Player")
If that's true then print to check that it's working.